# Atom editor regex expression to remove brackets from each time of text

Tags: regex, atom-editor

`Atom 1.40.0`

I am using atom and I have about 1000 lines of text. I want to remove just the open and closed brackets from this line of text. And I also want to remove the text and just keep the parts inside the brackets. I would like to use a regex to do this.

Case 1:
`alamo Gulf Coast Railroad (AGCR) (MMAX)`
to this:
`alamo Gulf Coast Railroad`

Case 2
`alamo Gulf Coast Railroad (AGCR) (MMAX)`
to this:
`AGCR MMAX`

Thanks advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
\((\S*)\)|(^.+?(?=\(| \())
```

[image]

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Xfj0LK/1)

1. Your Case 1 is covered by `(^.+?(?=\(| \())`, which can be referred to as `$2` (group 2).
2. Your Case 2 is covered by `\((\S*)\)`, which can be referred to as `$1` (group 1).

Therefore, if you want to turn

`alamo Gulf Coast Railroad (AGCR) (MMAX)` to `alamo Gulf Coast Railroad AGCR MMAX`

You can substitute with `$2$1`. See [here](https://www.regextester.com/?fam=110913) (in Substitution field add either `$1`, or `$2`, or `$2$1` depending what you need).